# Resource Group project error

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-web-api, azure-logic-apps

When trying to use this code from:
[LogicAppsAsyncResponseSample](https://github.com/jeffhollan/LogicAppsAsyncResponseSample/issues)
I created this method for my initial call:

```
    public async Task<dynamic> InsertRecords943(string interchangeId, [FromBody] dynamic inputjson)
    {
        Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
        RunningTasks[id] = string.Empty;
        new Thread(() => DoInsertRecords943(id, interchangeId, inputjson)).Start();   //Start the thread of work, but continue on before it completes
        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
        responseMessage.Headers.Add("location", String.Format("{0}://{1}/api/status/{2}", Request.RequestUri.Scheme, Request.RequestUri.Host, id));
        responseMessage.Headers.Add("retry-after", "20");
        return responseMessage;
    }
```

But Code Analysis is producing this error:

Error   CS1998  This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

So do I want to make the method synchronous:

```
public dynamic InsertRecords940(string interchangeId, [FromBody] dynamic inputjson)
```

Or change the new Thread line to be:

```
await Task.Run(DoInsertRecords943(id, interchangeId, inputjson));
```

Will the later even work, won't it still cause the caller to timeout?  Making it synchronous should actually work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes good catch - you likely want to make the method synchronous - as the await would make the action perform the "long-running step" synchronously which we don't want.

Hopefully that makes sense - if that works LMK and I will fix my code :)